# How do I create a Private EndPoint that has a Delegated Subnet in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-private-link

I have created a Private Azure Kubernetes Service. Now, I need to create a Private EndPoint that connect my existing VNET to the AZ Kubernetes.

```
az network private-endpoint create 
--name PrivateKubeApiEndpoint2 
--resource-group hat-eastus2-nprd-rg 
--vnet-name eastus-28828-nprd-vnet 
--subnet eastus2-28828-nprd-snet 
--private-connection-resource-id /subscriptions/***/resourcegroups/aks-demo2-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/aks-demo2-cluster 
--group-ids management 
--connection-name myKubeConnection
```

It gives me an error saying:

> (PrivateEndpointCreationNotAllowedAsSubnetIsDelegated) Private endpoint /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/hat-eastus2-nprd-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/PrivateKubeApiEndpoint2 cannot be created as subnet /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/hat-eastus2-nprd-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/eastus-28828-nprd-vnet/subnets/eastus2-28828-nprd-snet is delegated.

Question is: How do I assign a subnet that was set as delegated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it's impossible to create a private endpoint in the delegated subnet. See the limitation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/subnet-delegation-overview#impact-of-subnet-delegation-on-your-subnet) for the delegated subnet, it shows you:

> cannot be used with a private endpoint if the subnet is delegated

Comment: It is "Of course" impossible because you have delegated the subnet to another service, so if you host something in that subnet then the service that has been delegated rights to it could try to use a conflicting ip address.